# Display solution/file path in the Visual Studio IDE

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I frequently work with multiple instances of Visual Studio, often working on different branches of the same solution.

[Visual C++ 6.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B#Strictly_32-bit_versions) used to display the full path of the current source file in its title bar, but Visual Studio 2005 doesn't appear to do this. This makes it slightly more awkward than it should be to work out which branch of the solution I'm currently looking at (the quickest way I know of is to hover over a tab so you get the source file's path as a tooltip).

Is there a way to get the full solution or file path into the title bar, or at least somewhere that's always visible, so I can quickly tell which branch is loaded into each instance?

Comment: 11 years and still not available out of the box :-/

Comment: Preferences > Window:Title.  No plugin needed. => existed since 2017 at least.

Comment: @JasonLeMonier, I can't find this setting in Visual Studio but I can find it in Visual Studio Code, are you mixing them up? Perhaps you could post a fully fleshed out answer to make it clearer. EDIT - Just noticed you did post an answer, good.

Comment: @visitors: don't search for JasonLeMoniers answer as it is indeed for VS Code - sry JLM

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is not a native way to do it, but you can achieve it with a macro. The details are described here in full: *[How To Show Full File Path (or Anything Else) in VS 2005 Title Bar](https://www.helixoft.com/blog/how-to-show-full-file-path-or-anything-else-in-vs-2005-title-bar.html)*

You just have to add a little Visual Basic macro to the EvironmentEvents macro section and restart Visual Studio.

Note: The path will not show up when you first load Visual Studio, but it will whenever you change which file you are viewing. There is probably a way to fix this, but it doesn't seem like a big deal.

Comment: [File Path On Footer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d9fc97d4-3b42-4b56-ba47-23f8b81ebd17/) is also a good extension

Comment: @dan  ...but eats a line in the editor bottom (not in the status bar (you know, the blue one changing to orange when debugging)). Take it in consideration especially for little screens etc. Anyway thank you for the pointer.

Answer (score 33):

This is a extension available in the online gallery specifically tailored for this job. Checkout *[Labs > Visual Studio Extension: Customize Visual Studio Window Title](http://erwinmayer.com/labs/visual-studio-2010-extension-rename-visual-studio-window-title/)*.

Comment: Awesome. Minimalistic extension that just works. No config needed.

Comment: Works in 2015 as well

Comment: Works in 2017 as well

Comment: Works in 2019 as well. Optionally [Re-enable the Window Title Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53636350/re-enable-title-bar-in-visual-studio-2019) or just observe your changes in the Taskbar. Tested on v16.4.2.

Comment: Preferences > Window:Title.  No plugin needed.

Comment: @JasonLeMonier The question is tagged Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code. The two products are entirely different, like Visual Studio for Mac has nothing do to with the rest. You can thank the marketing team at MS for deliberately trying to confuse their customers/users and make their work harder.

Answer (score 17):

Check out the latest release of [VSCommands 2010 Lite](http://vscommands.com/download). It introduced a feature called Friendly Solution Name where you can set it to display the solution file path (or any part of it) in Visual Studio's main window title.

More details: http://vscommands.com/releasenotes/3.6.8.0 and http://vscommands.com/releasenotes/3.6.9.0

Comment: vs2013 version : http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c6d1c265-7007-405c-a68b-5606af238ece

Comment: All links (domain *vscommands.com*) seems to be broken (times out).

Comment: However, there is *[VSCommands for Visual Studio 2010](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SquaredInfinityJarekKardas.VSCommandsforVisualStudio2010)*. Is it the same?

Answer (score 5):

For Visual Studio 2008, a slightly better way to write the macro from the accepted answer is to use the Solution events instead of the document ones - this lets you always edit the title bar, even if you don't have a document selected.

Here's the macro my coworker and I put together based on the other one - you'll want to change lines 15-18 to pull your branch name from the source directory for however you're set up.

```
Private timer As System.Threading.Timer

Declare Auto Function SetWindowText Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As System.IntPtr, ByVal lpstring As String) As Boolean

Private _branchName As String = String.Empty

Private Sub SolutionEvents_Opened() Handles SolutionEvents.Opened
    Try
        If timer Is Nothing Then
            ' Create timer which refreshes the caption because
            ' IDE resets the caption very often
            Dim autoEvent As New System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(False)
            Dim timerDelegate As System.Threading.TimerCallback = _
                AddressOf tick
            timer = New System.Threading.Timer(timerDelegate, autoEvent, 0, 25)
        End If
        Dim sourceIndex As Integer = DTE.Solution.FullName.IndexOf("\Source")
        Dim shortTitle As String = DTE.Solution.FullName.Substring(0, sourceIndex)
        Dim lastIndex As Integer = shortTitle.LastIndexOf("\")
        _branchName = shortTitle.Substring(lastIndex + 1)
        showTitle(_branchName)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub SolutionEvents_BeforeClosing() Handles SolutionEvents.BeforeClosing
    If Not timer Is Nothing Then
        timer.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub


''' <summary>Dispose the timer on IDE shutdown.</summary>
Public Sub DTEEvents_OnBeginShutdown() Handles DTEEvents.OnBeginShutdown
    If Not timer Is Nothing Then
        timer.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub


'''<summary>Called by timer.</summary>
Public Sub tick(ByVal state As Object)
    Try
        showTitle(_branchName)
    Catch ex As System.Exception
    End Try
End Sub


'''<summary>Shows the title in main window.</summary>
Private Sub showTitle(ByVal title As String)
    SetWindowText(New System.IntPtr(DTE.MainWindow.HWnd), title & " - " & DTE.Name)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

#### How to customise the Visual Studio window title

Install the [Customize Visual Studio Window Title](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mayerwin.RenameVisualStudioWindowTitle) plugin.

After installing the extension, the settings can be found in the menu.

Menu *Tools* ► *Options* ► *Customize VS Window Title*.

**More information**

*Customize Visual Studio Window Title* is a lightweight extension to Visual Studio, which allows you to change the window title to include a folder tree:

[image]

#### Features

- A configurable minimum and maximum depth distance from the solution/project file
- Allows the use of special tags to help with many other possible scenarios, which include [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git), [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial), and [TFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Comment: Preferences > Window:Title.  No plugin needed.

Comment: @JasonLeMonier No such option exists in Visual Studio, which is the IDE that the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 3):

It's awkward indeed. Hovering on the tab is indeed one of the few things useful.

Alternative: right click on the file tab: *[Find your File Path in Visual Studio](http://weblogs.asp.net/piseth/archive/2008/11/08/find-your-file-path-in-visual-studio.aspx)*. It seems we have to do with that.

Answer (score 2):

I am using VSCommands 10 to show the full path of the solution file open.

```
Friendly Name: {repo}
Solution Path Regex: (?<repo>.*)
```

Now my main title window looks like this:

```
c:\repositories\acme.marketplace.trunk\Acme.Marketplace.web\Acme.Marketplace.Web.sln
```

I can quickly glance and see that I am working in the trunk folder or a rc folder because we use Mercurial (Hg) and keep separate folders for trunk, rc, preprod, prod like this:

```
c:\repositories\acme.marketplace.rc1
c:\repositories\acme.marketplace.rc2
c:\repositories\acme.marketplace.trunk
c:\repositories\acme.marketplace.preprod
c:\repositories\acme.marketplace.prod
```

Comment: Is it the same as *[VSCommands for Visual Studio 2010](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SquaredInfinityJarekKardas.VSCommandsforVisualStudio2010)*?

Answer (score 2):

As [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1764696/dan) also mentioned it in a comment, the [File Path On Footer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShemeerNS.FilePathOnFooter) extension serves the same purpose.

Answer (score 2):

### [TabsStudio](https://tabsstudio.com/) | US$49

It is a pretty good (although paid) Visual Studio extension that provides:

- Tab grouping
- Tab coloring
- Title transformation
- Lots of customization and extensions

[image: Tabs Studio Screenshot]

### [File Path On Footer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShemeerNS.FilePathOnFooter) | Free

It displays the full file path on the bottom of the editor window:

[image: File Path On Footer Screenshot]

### Honorable Mention: Visual Studio Code

Visual Studio Code [version 1.26 implemented breadcrumbs](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_26#_breadcrumbs) which displays the file path in a separate row at the top of the editor window when using tabs or inline the file name when in its own window.

[image: Visual Studio Code Breadcrumbs Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Related note: As an alternative, for Visual Studio 2005 you can use the command menu *File* → *Advanced Save Options*. The dialog displays the full path of the current file, and you are able to copy the text.

Answer (score 1):

Use the MKLINK command to create a link to your existing solution. As far as Visual Studio is concerned, it's working with the link file, but any changes go to the underlying .sln file.

I wrote a blog entry here about it...

http://willissoftware.com/?p=72

Comment: The link is broken (*"We can’t connect to the server at www.willissoftware.com."*). Domain expired?

Comment: This answer is not very useful with the broken link.

Answer (score 1):

For the people that didn't get the VB method to work (like me) you can use a plugin:

*[Customize Visual Studio Window Title](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f3f23845-5b1e-4811-882f-60b7181fa6d6)*

It was tested it in Visual Studio 2008 Ultimate. You can configure it in the *Options* menu of Visual Studio.

Comment: Preferences > Window:Title.  No plugin needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio 2010 or above you can you the extension "Visual Studio Window Title Changer".

Install this and use the following 'Window Title Setup' expression to display the solution path:

```
'sln_dir + "/" + orig_title'
```

Use the extension manager to download and install the extension. Details of the extension and how to use it can be found here:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2e8ebfe4-023f-4c4d-9b7a-d05bbc5cb239?SRC=VSIDE

Comment: The link is broken (404).

Comment: Preferences > Window:Title.  No plugin needed.

Answer (score -1):

File > Preferences > Settings >> Window:Title

I just changed ${activeEditorShort} => ${activeEditorLong}

within the setting:
${dirty}${activeEditorLong}${separator}${rootName}${separator}${appName}

Worked immediately when I clicked a file.

Great help right in the setting ...

Window: Title --
Controls the window title based on the active editor. Variables are substituted based on the context:

${activeEditorShort}: the file name (e.g. myFile.txt).

${activeEditorMedium}: the path of the file relative to the workspace folder (e.g. myFolder/myFileFolder/myFile.txt).

...

Visual Studio Code
Version: 1.56.2
Date: 2021-05-12

I found one reference saying this existed since 2017.

Comment: The question is for Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code.