# Does Visual Studio provide a way to show file paths on files with the same name?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm very adjusted to the JetBrains products which, when you have multiple files open with the same name, append the path name to those filesnames so you can tell them apart.

For instance, an index.html file from /Home and another from /View would be shown in the code editor as "/Home/index.html" and "/View/index.html".

In Visual Studio, when I have both index.html files open in the code editor, it just lists both of them as "index.html" and so I have no way to easily tell which of those files is from the /Home dir and which is from the /View dir.

Is there an extension that provides this functionality?

---

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2015.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505/display-solution-file-path-in-visual-studio-ide

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486062/display-folder-name-in-visual-studio-open-file-tab