# How can I change a source file in the GSL library and save it

Tags: c, visual-studio, gsl, model-fitting

I want to change the source file trust.c in the gsl library . How can I do that and save it ? It doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: how did you try it? You will have to compile the library again after you change it, of course. And you will have to make sure your program uses the changed version of the library and not the original one

Comment: I opened the trust.c file in visual studio, did the necessary changes and saves it and rebuilt the solution and the library . I tried using a breakpoint and debugging but the program still tells me that the breakpoint will not be hit because the source file is different than the original file .

Comment: Do you have the ability to [view full file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505/display-solution-file-path-in-the-visual-studio-ide) in your IDE?  Sometimes the file being fed into the compiler is not the one you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

To change and save a source file in the GSL library, you need to locate the particular source file you want to modify. Once you have found it, open it in a text editor. Make the changes you want and save the file. Note that if your changes require recompiling the library, then you will need to do that as well.

Comment: I did try that and now it's working but it's giving me a linker issue. Dies that mean i didn't recompile the library correctly ?