# How to view the full solution path in VisualStudio on macos?

Tags: visual-studio

I have cloned a solution and want to ensure the path is to the clone. I can not see it in the default Visual Studio layout.

There are a couple of questions directly relevant:

- [Blog: How to show full file path in Visual Studio Code](https://ivan-lim.com/show-full-file-path-visual-studio-code)  . This one shows what I want but it might be on Windows: in any case it does not work for me: typing in `Window title` does nothing
- Stackoverflow question from the dawn of existence: [Display solution/file path in the Visual Studio IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505/display-solution-file-path-in-the-visual-studio-ide)  . This is from August 2008 and the answers are > 12 years old.

Is there a macos updated answer for this?